# Can't run npm install

Tags: node.js, magento, npm

In [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html) it says to run `npm install`, but I get this error when I run `sudo npm install`.

```
sudo npm install
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/mg/package.json'
npm WARN mg No description
npm WARN mg No repository field.
npm WARN mg No README data
npm WARN mg No license field.
```

without sudo:

```
npm install
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/mg/package.json'
npm WARN mg No description
npm WARN mg No repository field.
npm WARN mg No README data
npm WARN mg No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /var/www/html/mg/node_modules/.staging
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/mg/node_modules/.staging'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/mg/node_modules/.staging']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/var/www/html/mg/node_modules/.staging' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/mg/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried without sudo ?

Comment: See edit in OP.

Comment: Can you add your package.json ? This issue normally occurs when you don't have this file.

Comment: I had to remove .sample from it...  https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/package.json.sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a `package.json` file for that to work.

You can create it by running:

```
npm init
```

See also:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init
- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json