# Spotify Web API

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am attempting to set up a way to pull metadata from a spotify playlist for a research project. I am following the tutorial on this site https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/ . I got to the part where I install the OAuth examples from this site https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples . When I type "npm install" on the command prompt[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYUoo.png) I get the following error. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895459/cant-run-npm-install)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't ran `npm init`.
First, to install any npm package you need to initialize npm to that directory.

In your command line on the same directory run `npm init`, After this command is done, it will create a `package.json` in your folder and then you can go with the Spotify instruction.

Comment: I actually deleted it all and redid all the steps and it worked but when I run "cd authorization_code" it says path not found but it is in the folder. Additionally, I cant open the html file or app.js file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: check the directory is available from the command line running "dir" or "ls", if it doesn't show you the directory on that path, it might mean that you are in the wrong path on your command line

Comment: also make sure authorization_code file is not a hidden file